# How do i set the background image using jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#Lines').click(function () {
    $('html').css('background-image', 'url("../Images/banner.jpg")');
  });
});
</script>

<a id="Lines" href="Home.aspx?PostId=<%#Eval("PostId") %>" >Read Post</a>
```

I am using C# coding . When I click on the Read Post link it goes to the another page and the background image which i set in jQuery is no longer available , It shows only 2 or 3 seconds. after that it shows default background image. how can i set the background image permanant using jQuery.

Comment: Do you want to use `"Lines"` only to set background?

Answer (score 0):

When you move to another page, JavaScript starts from a "clean slate" so any changes you make in the previous page don't carry on automatically to the next.

When you change the background picture you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) to save the setting and read it again in the next page.

Change the code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Lines').click(function () {
        $('html').css('background-image', 'url("../Images/banner.jpg")');

        // save the background image to localstorage    
        if (localStorage) {
            localStorage.setItem('bg', '../Images/banner.jpg');
        }
    });
});
```

and put this script on every page where you want to use the new background:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if( localStorage && localStorage.getItem('bg') ) {
        $('html').css('background-image', 'url("' + localStorage.getItem('bg') + '")');
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FkT7P/)

Comment: but the jquery background image applied for the home page too . because the when i click in href link it goes to the home.aspx?postid=2 . So how can i do not apply jquery background image for home page and apply for home.aspx?postid=2 .

Comment: Don't put the script that's marked "put this script on every page" to the home page.